# Raspberry - Cannot create platform OpenGL context

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, opengl-es, stellarium

i'm trying to install Stellarium on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB ram). I'm following the instructions [here](http://%20https://snapcraft.io/install/stellarium-plars/raspbian). After installation, i tried to run the program using `snap run stellarium-plars`, but it doesn't work (only a small empty window opens). On the terminal i read a long output, i think the problem is here:

`QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled`

But i enabled OpenGL in `raspi-config`. How can i debug the problem? This is the full output on terminal after running the program:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
[ This is Stellarium 0.20.1 - https://stellarium.org/ ]
[ Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Fabien Chereau et al.       ]
 -----------------------------------------------------
Writing log file to: "/home/pi/snap/stellarium-plars/75/.stellarium/log.txt"
File search paths:
  0 .  "/home/pi/snap/stellarium-plars/75/.stellarium"
  1 .  "/snap/stellarium-plars/75/bin/../share/stellarium"
Config file is:  "/home/pi/snap/stellarium-plars/75/.stellarium/config.ini"
Default surface format:  QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
Desired surface format:  QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
StelGLWidget constructor
StelGraphicsScene constructor
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::save: Painter not active
QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
Segmentation error
```

Comment: Try the command glxinfo to know if your machine is well configured. The output is kinda long

Comment: Hi, thank you, here's the output: https://pastebin.com/81DYJ2DP What should i look for?

Comment: For such line : "OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.3.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10". Which I got from your pastebin. So it looks like you have opengl ready to use.
I'm out of idea :/
The instructions you gave are using snap. Maybe try a normal installation ?

Comment: Ok i can try with normal installation, i choose the snap method because it was faster. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sure ! And it should work fine. If you find the reason or solution, please mind to answer yourself your question :)